# How to return derived type?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a Validator class and derived classes from it; 
When i'm trying to return pointer to derived class then method return base class(Validator) instead of Derived.

```cpp
class Validator
{
public:
    std::string m_name = "BaseValidator";

    static const std::map<std::string, Validator *> validators();

    static Validator *getByName(std::string &name);
};


const std::map<std::string, Validator*> Validator::validators()
{
    std::map<std::string, Validator*> result;
    //RequiredValidator is derived
    result["required"] = new RequiredValidator();
    return result;
}

Validator* Validator::getByName(std::string &name)
{
    auto g_validators = Validator::validators();
    auto validator = g_validators.find(name);
    if(validator != g_validators.end()){
        std::cout << "getByName: " << validator->second->m_name << std::endl;
        return validator->second;
    }else{
        std::cerr << "Unknow type of validator: " << name << std::endl;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

//output BaseValidator but i need RequiredValidator


class RequiredValidator : public Validator
{
public:
    std::string m_name = "RequiredValidator";
};
```

Comment: Option 1: Instead of using `m_name`, directly, use a `virtual` function `getName()` and make sure to implement that in the derived class. Option 2: Set the value of `m_name` to one corresponding to the derived class. I recommend using the first option.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? `m_name` not being dynamically solved? Or the return type of `getByName`?

Comment: void Validator::validateModel(Model &model, const std::vector<std::string> &attrNames)
{
   validateAttribute(model, *name);
}
//problem when i'm trying call this

Comment: On a side note, the parameter for `getByName` should be `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returning a derived instance, but since `validator` is a `Validator*`, you're looking at the `m_name` member of `Validator`, not the one of `RequiredValidator`.
(Despite having the same name, they are distinct variables. There are no "virtual variables".)

There are a couple of options;

- You can have a virtual `getName` function and override it in every subclass.
- Set the *base* `m_name` in derived classes, for instance by making the name a parameter of the base constructor.

Example:

```
class Validator
{
public:
    Validator(const std::string& name = "BaseValidator") : m_name(name) {};
    // ...
};

class RequiredValidator : public Validator
{
public:
    RequiredValidator() : Validator("RequiredValidator") {}
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared two member variables named `m_name`, one in `Validator` and one in `RequiredValidator`. Other than having the same name these two variables are completely unrelated. Your compiler will probably have printed a warning about the second shadowing the first.

Which variable you access depends on the type of the variable that you are accessing it from.

For example:

```
RequiredValidator r;
std::cout << r.m_name << "\n"; // prints "RequiredValidator"
Validator* v = &r;
std::cout << v->m_name << "\n"; // prints "BaseValidator"
std::cout << dynamic_cast<RequiredValidator*>(v)->m_name << "\n"; // prints "RequiredValidator"
```

There are a couple of solutions to this. The first is to simply set the value of the `BaseValidator` variable in the RequiredValidator constructor:

```
class Validator
{
public:
   std::string m_name;
   Validator( const std::string& name = "BaseValidator" )
   :m_name( name )
   {
   }
};

class RequiredValidator : public Valdiator
{
public:
    RequiredValidator()
    : Validator("RequiredValidator")
    {}
};
```

The more conventional solution would be to use a virtual method instead:

```
class Validator
{
public:
  virtual std::string getName() { return "BaseValidator"; }
};

class RequiredValidator : public Valdiator
{
public:
  virtual std::string getName() override { return "RequiredValidator"; }
};
```