# How to call exact derived class method?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

In continuation of my previous question:
[How to return derived type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194395/how-to-return-derived-type)

> I have a Validator class and derived classes from it; When i'm trying
>   to return pointer to derived class then method return base
>   class(Validator) instead of Derived.

I modified my class as next:

```
class Validator
{
public:
    std::string m_name = "BaseValidator";

    static const std::map<std::string, Validator *> validators();

    void validateModel(Model &model, const std::vector<std::string> &attrNames);
    static Validator *getByName(std::string &name);

    virtual void validateAttribute(Model &model, const std::string &attribute);
    virtual ~Validator();

    virtual std::string name() const;
};

const std::map<std::string, Validator*> Validator::validators()
{
    std::map<std::string, Validator*> result;
    result["required"] = new RequiredValidator();
    return result;
}

void Validator::validateModel(Model &model, const std::vector<std::string> &attrNames)
{      
     validateAttribute(model, name.at(0));    
}

Validator* Validator::getByName(std::string &name)
{
    auto g_validators = Validator::validators();
    auto validator = g_validators.find(name);
    if(validator != g_validators.end()){
        return validator->second;
    }else{
        std::cerr << "Unknow type of validator: " << name << std::endl;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

void Validator::validateAttribute(Model &model, const std::string &attribute)
{
    (void)model;
    (void)attribute;
    std::cout << this->name() << std::endl;
}

//------------------

class RequiredValidator : public Validator
{
public:
    std::string m_name = "RequiredValidator";

    void validateAttribute(Model &model, std::string &attribute);
    ~RequiredValidator();
    std::string name() const;
};


std::string RequiredValidator::name() const
{
    return m_name;
}

void RequiredValidator::validateAttribute(Model &model, std::string &attribute)
{
    (void) model;
    (void) attribute;
    std::cout << "RequiredValidator!!!" << std::endl;
}

RequiredValidator::~RequiredValidator()
{

}


//------------------

auto validator = Validator::getByName("required");

validator->name();// will output RequiredValidator

//next i'm calling 

validator->validateModel(); // whos calling validateAttribute() inside
//and it's output Validator::validateAttribute() //but i wan't
//RequiredValidator::validateAttribute(); 
//where i was wrong with logic???
```

> The same virtual method name() working as i want, but
>   validateAttribute() called from base class only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at how you defined `void RequiredValidator::validateAttribute()`

You may note that the signature is slightly different than the base (`std::string &attribute` isn't `const`)

there's a keyword `override` that would help with the compiler catching these types of typos.

Comment: Need i redefine then "virtual" keyword? Because "error: non-virtual member function marked 'override' hides virtual member function"

Comment: the `validateAttribute` signature has to be identical in base and in the derived class

Comment: Only one thing: undefined reference to `Validator::name[abi:cxx11]() const'.
How to fix it?

Comment: @exru: it says that it lacks the implementation of `virtual std::string name() const;`.

Comment: Thanks bro, i fixed it myself. It says what: 1.listen the compilator 2. teach english 3. read docas e.t.c. All troublshooting in my bad english. But i'm trying)) And i spent a lot of time with PHP. I'm writing on C++ only 2 month))) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly, as others have pointed out,

> §13.1 where the Standard discusses about declarations that cannot be
>   overloaded states -
>
> Parameter declarations that differ only in the presence or absence of
>   const and/or volatile are equivalent. That is, the const and volatile
>   type-specifiers for each parameter type are ignored [...]
>
> Only the const and volatile type-specifiers at the outermost level of
>   the parameter type specification are ignored in this fashion; const
>   and volatile type-specifiers buried within a parameter type
>   specification are significant and can be used to distinguish
>   overloaded function declarations. [...]
>
> when determining which function is being declared, defined, or called.
>   "In particular, for any type T, “pointer to T,” “pointer to const T,”
>   and “pointer to volatile T” are considered distinct parameter types,
>   as are “reference to T,” “reference to const T,” and “reference to
>   volatile T.”

Therefore,

```
void validateAttribute(Model &model, std::string &attribute) override;
```

is not the same as

```
void validateAttribute(Model &model, const std::string &attribute);
```

- Secondly, you can avoid bumping into such errors, if you have `C++11` or newer with the use of the `override` keyword in the function declaration, as shown below.

With the **override** keyword, this code will not let you compile unless the function signature in the derived class matches the one in the base class!

```
class RequiredValidator : public Validator
{
public:
    std::string m_name = "RequiredValidator";

    void validateAttribute(Model &model, std::string &attribute) override;
    ~RequiredValidator();
    std::string name() const;
};
```

EDIT: p.s. `override` requires `virtual` keyword. Hence,

```
virtual void validateAttribute(Model &model, std::string &attribute) override;
```

Comment: @exru, actually, if there was a const but not a reference, then it would've been ok to overload, i.e. `void validateAttribute(Model &model, std::string attribute)` and `void validateAttribute(Model &model, const std::string &attribute)` would not have this problem. (BUT of course, it is not what we want to do..) I just wanted to elaborate a point. The difference is for **references** and **pointers**! For them `const` makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks bro. I fixed!

Comment: @JoeyMallone Did you mean `const std::string attribute` in the second signature of your comment? Because `T` and `const T` are mangled the same in signatures, but `T` and `const T&` are certainly not...

Comment: @MaxLanghof, yes. But I can't edit the comment now. :(

I mean't, `void validateAttribute(Model &model, std::string attribute)` and `void validateAttribute(Model &model, const std::string attribute)` would've been ok for overloading. No `&` in both declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Removing all of the irrelevant code let's look at both your base and inherited classes' signatures:

```
class Validator {
public:
    virtual void validateAttribute(Model &model, const std::string &attribute);
};

class RequiredValidator : public Validator {
public:
    void validateAttribute(Model &model, std::string &attribute);
};
```

In the base class's `::validateAttribute()` you have for its parameters `Model& model` and `const std::string& attribute`, and in the derived class's `::validateAttribute()` you have for its parameters `Model &model`, and `std::string& attribute`.

The conflict here is `const std::string&` and `std::string&`. Either make the two functions match exactly beforehand or in your case because you are trying to use polymorphism you can in your derived class fix this by doing this:

```
/*virtual*/ void validateAttribute( Model& model, std::string& string ) override;
```

The `override` keyword here will generate a compiler error for you explaining what your problem is. Don't forget to add `virtual` too if you plan on inheriting from this derived class.